# Unable to create a file on Ubuntu server using Flask and Python

Tags: python, apache, flask

I am using f = open('name.json','w+') to create a new file and write to it. But i am unable to create the file. Apache server logs show "No such file exists."

Comment: `fopen`? I know only `open` :) What's the current working directory? Do you get any exception?

Comment: yeah.. sorry for the typo. no, i am not getting any exception. it worked perfectly on localhost. But it is giving this error pn hosted ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving absolute path. I was trying all combinations of paths and also gave absolute path /var/www/arxiv/static/data/name.json and it worked.